# H2 - Build and execute query in Java to date comparison

Tags: java, datetime, h2

I want to create a table containing all record of another table which BirthDate is < of a certain Date

I have tried to build and execute this query in my Java application.

The Date of comparison (2016-12-31) is a String and BirthDate is stored as datetime in H2 database.

```sql
CREATE TABLE table1 AS
SELECT *
FROM temp
WHERE FORMATDATETIME(BirthDate,'yyyy-MM-dd') < 2016-12-31
GROUP BY Cod, Id
ORDER BY Cod, BirthDate
```

When the query is execute I've got this error:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Data conversion error converting "2016-12-31"; SQL statement:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `BirthDate` is a date or datetime value it shouldn't be converted to a character string value for such comparison. However, for some comparison operations you may need to convert a datetime value to a date value, in that case use `CAST(datetime AS DATE)`. In your query it isn't really needed.

The date literal cannot be written as `2016-12-31`, such expression means a numeric expression with two subtractions. The date literal should be written as `DATE '2016-12-31'`.

```sql
CREATE TABLE table1 AS
SELECT *
FROM temp
WHERE BirthDate < DATE '2016-12-31'
GROUP BY Cod, Id
ORDER BY Cod, BirthDate
```

The `GROUP BY` clause in this query is also not valid. H2 is not very strict in that area and may accept such query *if there are no duplicate rows with the same values in grouped columns*, but you shouldn't rely on such behavior. Non-grouped columns may not be selected, they may be only aggregated. *If `Id` is a primary key*, you should remove this clause as useless.

```sql
CREATE TABLE table1 AS
SELECT *
FROM temp
WHERE BirthDate < DATE '2016-12-31'
ORDER BY Cod, BirthDate
```